# AutoHotkey emulating arrow keys with [Right CTRL] + i, j,k,l

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, arrow-keys

I want to be more productive while writing source code. Navigating a text using arrow keys seems to be not effective as you need to move your right arm. I want to emulate arrow keys using combination with [Right CTRL] and one of the keys [i], [j], [k], [l]. I created a script for AutoHotkey:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

>^i::Send {Up}
>^j::Send {Left}
>^k::Send {Down}
>^l::Send {Right}
```

Everything seems to be ok until you try to navigate by words (Left CTRL + left/right arrow). I want [Right CTRL] + [Left CTRL] + [j] to be acting like [Left CTRL] + [Left Arrow].

Comment: Works fine here: **`<^>^j::Send ^{Left}`** and **`<^>^l::Send ^{Right}`**

Comment: user3419297, thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: What I'm left with is:
`>^i::Send {Up}
>^j::Send {Left}
>^k::Send {Down}
>^l::Send {Right}
<^>^i::Send ^{Up}
<^>^j::Send ^{Left}
<^>^k::Send ^{Down}
<^>^l::Send ^{Right}
+>^i::Send +{Up}
+>^j::Send +{Left}
+>^k::Send +{Down}
+>^l::Send +{Right}
+<^>^i::Send +^{Up}
+<^>^j::Send +^{Left}
+<^>^k::Send +^{Down}
+<^>^l::Send +^{Right}`

Navigation and selection works fine both by characters and words